# Blazor component event callback

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

I have created an blazor component (mycomponent) which is as below

```
<SfDropDownList TValue="string" TItem="ChillCategoryItem" PopupHeight="230px"
                            Placeholder="Select a Category" DataSource="@chillCategoryItems"
                            ValueChange="ChangeCountry">
                <DropDownListEvents TItem="ChillCategoryItem" TValue="string"></DropDownListEvents>
                <DropDownListFieldSettings Text="Name" Value="Id"></DropDownListFieldSettings>
            </SfDropDownList>
```

and the code is as below

```
  public class ChillCategoryItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public async Task ChangeCountry(Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.ChangeEventArgs<string, ChillCategoryItem> args)
{
    await OnStateChange.InvokeAsync(args.ItemData.Id);
}
[Parameter]
public EventCallback OnStateChange { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public List<ChillCategoryItem> chillCategoryItems { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public List<ChillCategoryItem> chillerType { get; set; }
```

Now I am trying to use the above component in one of my blazor app as below

```
 <MyCompnent chillCategoryItems=chillCategoryItems chillerType=chillerType  OnStateChange="@ChangeCountry">
</MyCompnent>
```

the event I am not able to handle properly

```
public async void ChangeCountry(string category)
{
   
    //do some stuff
}
```

The error I am getting is like "can not convert method group to event call back"

Comment: OnstateChanged event callback has 0 arguments, but change country has 1 string argument. Declare it like EventCallback<string>  OnStateChanged and it should work.

Comment: Also, it is bad practice to use async void method, use async Task instead. I recommend reading this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void

Comment: @JanBejvl error is gone but now no call back is working

Comment: Is ChangeCountry(ChangeEventArgs<string, ChillCategoryItem> args) inside <MyComponent> being called properly? Or when  OnStateChange.InvokeAsync(args.ItemData.Id) is invoked nothing happens in parent component?

Comment: @JanBejvl there was some issue now it's working as expected. But at the first time it is not working and other times it is working.

Comment: @JanBejvl This is the exact use case for async void. From your link - `Void-returning async methods have a specific purpose: to make asynchronous event handlers possible`

Comment: @BenSampica I see your point, but this is not the case in my opinion. Blazor’s EventCalback is not a classic subscribable event handler. I'm not a pro in this, but I assume that when you invoke EventCalback with .InvokeAsync(), there is no reason to use an async void handler. Are there some caveats that I should know about?

Comment: Nope - I’m just flat wrong. You’re correct, Blazor event callbacks are asynchronous and awaitable. https://blazor-university.com/components/component-events/